# Calculate 3 days back but skipping weekends

Tags: excel, google-sheets

We have a spreadsheet where we keep track of when a coworker has worked on a specific project. This contains a column for the dates, and then a bunch of columns for the projects. Whenever someone worked on a project, we write an x in the projects cell.

Now we'd like to project the projects column into the past by 3 days, but skipping the weekends. Essentially when someone worked on the project on Friday, they also worked on it, Thursday, Wednesday, and Tuesday. The result should look like this:

|  |  | Project A | Result |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Weekend |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-02 | Weekday |  | X |  |
| 2023-01-03 | Weekday |  | X |  |
| 2023-01-04 | Weekday |  | X |  |
| 2023-01-05 | Weekday | X | X |  |
| 2023-01-06 | Weekday |  | X |  |
| 2023-01-07 | Weekend |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-08 | Weekend |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-09 | Weekday |  | X |  |
| 2023-01-10 | Weekday | X | X |  |
| 2023-01-11 | Weekday |  |  |  |

I hope this example is clear enough. Date 2023-01-05 has an X (or a `TRUE`) in Project A column. We can therefore fill 2023-01-05 until 2023-01-02 with X's because there's no weekend in between. 2023-01-10 has an X, but when we try to go back, there's a weekend, and so we have to fill 2023-01-10, 2023-01-09, 2023-01-06, 2023-01-05.

I tried making three columns, one check the cell back one day. Another one check the day 2 days ago, and so forth. Then using the OR formula to check whether any of these columns is true to generate a new column. This obviously doesn't solve the weekend problem.

[image]

Pointers in the right direction for Google Sheets would be nice, but Excel is also good for me.

Comment: You need to know if you are using Excel or Googlesheets. Things behave differently.

Comment: In Excel, if the date is entered in cell A1 in a recognisable format, then "=A1-3" will calculate 3 days prior. There are date functions that recognise weekends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within GSheets you can try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A2:A),LAMBDA(z,IF(LEN(XLOOKUP(A2:A,z,z,)),"x",))(FLATTEN(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(ax,bx,IF(bx<>"x",,TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(LAMBDA(z,FILTER(z,NOT(REGEXMATCH(WEEKDAY(z)&"","1|7"))))(offset(ax,-(ROW(ax)-2),0,ROW(ax)-1,1)),1,0),4,1))))))),))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the solution I'm looking for. Any idea why GSheets gives me a `#REF` error when I try to copy the formula through C? `Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3.`

Comment: Hi it's an arrayformula and auto applies to the whole column. Not necessary to drag it down. Delete any existing formulas from C3 to downside.

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you very much! Will take me a bit to work through the formula to understand how it's working.

Answer (score 1):

For Office 365, assuming the *Date* and *Project A* ranges are `A2:A12` and `C2:C12` respectively:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A2:A12,
    ξ,C2:C12,
    REPT("X",1-ISNA(MATCH(ζ,TOCOL(FILTER(WORKDAY(+ζ,-SEQUENCE(,4,0)),ξ="X")),0)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

in GS:

```
=INDEX(IF(""<>IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, FLATTEN(LAMBDA(x, 
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(WEEKDAY(x, 2)&"", "6|7"),,x)),,9^9))), " "), 9^9, 4))
 (FILTER(A:A, C:C="X")-SEQUENCE(1, 6, ))), 1, )), "X", ))
```

[image]